# Return AWS 'VPN Tunnel Status' with AWS Powershell Tools

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have numerous VPN tunnels that connect various virtual devices in different VPCs.

How can I use the [AWS Powershell tools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html) to query the `tunnel status` of each tunnel associated with a `vpn connection` to determine if they are `up` or `down`.  `tunnel status` is available in the AWS web GUI under VPC > VPN Connections > select connection > tunnel details subtab.

The command:

`get-ec2vpnconnection`

returns an object with the property `state`,  but this is not the status of an individual tunnel; this is the states of the vpn connection as a whole.

How can I use the AWS Powershell Tools to obtain the status of an individual VPN tunnel in a VPN connection?

Comment: While researching an answer for you I found [this blog post](https://www.yobyot.com/aws/check-monitor-aws-vpn-status/2017/03/13/) that I think describes the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPC VPN Tunnel Status can, in fact, be monitored with the AWS PowerShell tools.  The below script is reproduced from [a blog post on yobyot.com](https://www.yobyot.com/aws/check-monitor-aws-vpn-status/2017/03/13/) by Alex Neihaus on March 13, 2017, licensed under the Apache license 2.0 (included).

This script returns the VPNconnection ID, whether it is up or down, and and status messages that are associated with it.  It does this by obtaining the vgw-telemetry property of a given VPN tunnel.

```
<#Copyright 2017 Air11 Technology LLC

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License. #>

Get-EC2VpnConnection | Select-Object -Property VpnConnectionId, VgwTelemetry | ` # Pass all objects to the pipeline
ForEach-Object -Process {

$connectionID = $_.VpnConnectionId # get connection ID
$_.VgwTelemetry | ForEach-Object {
    # There are multiple Amazon.Model.EC2.VgwTelemetry objects in each Amazon.Model.EC2.VPNConnection
    if (($_.status).value -ne 'UP')
    {
        Write-Host "Connection $connectionID is $(($_.status).value) and has a status message of $(($_.StatusMessage))"
        # Uncomment the next statement and change the arn to send a message to an SNS topic
        # Publish-SNSMessage -TopicArn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:01234567890:your-SNS-topic -Subject "VPN Status Alert!" -Message "The $ConnectionID is showing it's ($_.status).value"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Connection $connectionID is $(($_.status).value) and has 
a status message of $(($_.StatusMessage))"

        }
    }
}
```